# How to test incoming request from client and send back response?

Tags: java, rest, server, testng, rest-assured

I would like to test incoming request from client and send back response, but i haven't found easy way to realize it.

I have created simple test by using spark and testng(code below). The problem in the method which don't wait on incoming request and finishing instance in few seconds after ran.

```
@Test
private void server(){

    port(4321);

    post("/", (req, res) -> {
        System.out.println(req.body());
        return "some_text";
    });

   
}
```

1. How to make waiting on incoming request?
2. Does it possible to use Rest-assured framework for getting request from client?
3. Does exists framework for creating test server?

I will glad for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thread.sleep() to add delay in the execution. The better approach would be using a mock server like [MOCK-SERVER](https://www.mock-server.com/) or Wiremock to mock the third party dependencies and make it independent.